# What is the legal size of cricket bat?

Tags: rules, cricket

Can a batsman use bigger or shorter bat? What is legal weight of bat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bat sizes do vary but must all conform to the requirements laid down in the Laws of Cricket, specifically in [Law 6](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-6-the-bat/) and [Appendix E](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/appendix-e-the-bat/). There is no restriction on the weight of a bat, but there are certain restrictions on the length (not to exceed 96.5cm) and width (not to exceed 10.8cm).